# Shared Spock mock verification

Tags: java, mocking, spock

Let say I'm testing a bunch of servlets, and I want to make sure that some of them (not all) set the right headers. I can do this:

```
then:
1 * response.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=' + 3600)
1 * response.setHeader('X-Foo', 'bar')
```

How do I put them in a method (either in superclass or utility), so I can do this instead:

```
then:
verifyCorrectHeader()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Spock Documentation](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.1-rc-1/all_in_one.html) you can use **Explicit Interaction Blocks** for this:

```
def 'the test'() {
    when:
    //...
    then:
    interaction verifyCorrectHeader
}

def verifyCorrectHeader = {
    1 * response.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=' + 3600)
    1 * response.setHeader('X-Foo', 'bar')
}
```

> public void interaction(Closure block):
>   Encloses one or more interaction definitions in a then block...

See [MockingApi.interaction(Closure block)](http://spockframework.org/spock/javadoc/1.0/spock/lang/MockingApi.html#interaction-groovy.lang.Closure-) documentation for detailed explanation and more examples.